# lat, lon in Google (static) Maps vs Google map with globe view

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-earth, google-maps-api

I am trying to find latitude and longitude of some visual feature using Google map and I found that switching between globe view and flat (not globe) view (like in Google static maps) changes the position of the feature for the same latitude and longitude.

Can someone explain why is this happening?
And is there a way to convert latitude and longitude from globe view to flat view so that it corresponds to the same visual position.
Please see attached images.

[image: Google maps with flat view like static maps]

[image: Google maps with globe view (like Google Earth?)]

Comment: Sad to say, not every image ever taken is perfectly registered to the real world. Given that a tenth of a second can be, at worst, accurate to 3 meters, that it was this close is actually astounding.

Comment: Is this really about the image registration issue (the way Google maps vs Google Earth did)? Or is it the convention of (lat, lon) that is used by Google maps vs Google Earth?
(obviously, if you change the datum convention, same lat, lon goes to different position)

Comment: Well, if you do some research on the underlying images, you might find both are off by more than that, but on a global basis, on two different collections, probably at different angles, I doubt you have any way to know.

Comment: The globe view, in some regions including the one in your example, uses a different image collection than the flat view. So when you switch between the two, the imagery changes as well, and any registration difference between the two is noticeable, as you can see. I believe both use WGS84 for the datum. The globe view also uses a 3-dimensional view, and I've sometimes noticed glitches with placemarks positions too, like they are floating above or below the surface somehow.

Comment: If you look in Google Earth pro, you can display the images taken at different time, and you will see they "move" around

Comment: Ok. Seem it is registration issue then. I checked some other places and, globe view and flat view seem to agree there quite well. Thanks Vince, FSimardGIS and JGH.
Does anyone know or point me to a python API to get the images that belong to globe view (Google Static Maps = flat view; I checked. So not that).

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy is due to registration issue as pointed by @Vince. I checked some other places and, globe view and flat view seem to agree there quite well; which also means both uses WGS84 for the datum as pointed by @FSimardGIS.